# Receiving "Request Entity Cannot be Empty" from paramaterized RESTful GET operation

Tags: java, rest

New to java programming and still learning.  I've built a RESTful service and I'm trying to pass in a parameter for a GET routine and I'm getting back a state 400 saying that the "Request entity cannot be empty".  When I call the non-parameterized GET, the data comes back just fine.  I've stripped down all the functionality of the parameterized GET to just return a simple string and I'm still getting the same message.  Searched all over and can't find anything that's very helpful.

Below is the code that I'm running for the service.  The method "GetChildAllInfo" makes a call to a local mySQL instance and returns a list of objects; that one works just fine.  The parameterized one returns nothing, not even an exception.

Any help would be tremendously appreciated.  Even if it's a ridiculously simple solution like a syntax error that I may have missed.  AND I'm willing to accept any other advice on what you see in the code as well.  Thanks!

```
    package allowanceManagerChild;

    import java.util.Set;
    import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
    import javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo;
    import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
    import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
    import javax.ws.rs.GET;
    import javax.ws.rs.Path;
    import javax.ws.rs.PUT;
    import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
    import com.google.gson.Gson;

    @Path("allowanceManagerChild")
    public class AllowanceManagerChild {

        @Context
        private UriInfo context;

        /**
         * Creates a new instance of AllowanceManagerChild
         */
        public AllowanceManagerChild() {
        }

        @GET
        @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        public String getJson() {

            String response = "";
            Set<Child> children = Child.GetAllChildInfo();
            for (Child child : children){
                Gson gson = new Gson();
                String json = gson.toJson(child);
                response = response + json;
            }
            return response;
        }

        @GET
        @Path("/{childID}")
        @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        public String getJson(int childID) {
            String response = "";
            try{
    //        Set<Child> children = Child.GetChildInfo(id);
    //        for (Child child : children){
    //            Gson gson = new Gson();
    //            String json = gson.toJson(child);
    //            response = response + json;
    //        }
                response = "Made it here"; //Integer.toString(childID);
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                response = e.toString();
            }
            return response;
        }

        /**
         * PUT method for updating or creating an instance of AllowanceManagerChild
         * @param content representation for the resource
         */
        @PUT
        @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        public void putJson(String content) {
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the `@PathParam` annotation to the method parameter might help:

```
@GET
@Path("/{childID}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String getJson(@PathParam("childID") int childID) {
```

See the [RESTful Web Services Developer's Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19776-01/820-4867/6nga7f5nc/index.html) for more details.

Comment: That did it!  Thanks for your help!

Comment: @spice glad it helped! Please mark the answer as "accepted" so that the question will not appear as "unanswered".